# is it possible to use TWO where clauses in ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE?

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I'm trying to set two columns with two different where clauses in `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`, for example:

```
INSERT INTO table AS t (id, detail, areaid)
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET detail = EXCLUDED.detail
WHERE (t.detail IS NULL AND EXCLUDED.detail IS NOT NULL),
areaid = EXCLUDED.areaid
WHERE (t.areaid IS NULL AND EXCLUDED.areaid IS NOT NULL);
```

which will result to a syntax error. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, but you could do:

```
INSERT INTO "table" AS t (id, detail, areaid)
VALUES (...) | SELECT ...
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET detail = CASE WHEN t.detail IS NULL
                     AND EXCLUDED.detail IS NOT NULL
                  THEN EXCLUDED.detail
                  ELSE t.detail
             END,
    areaid = CASE WHEN t.areaid IS NULL
                     AND EXCLUDED.areaid IS NOT NULL
                  THEN EXCLUDED.areaid
                  ELSE t.areaid
             END;
```

The downside is that `detail` and `areaid` will always be updated, even if the value doesn't change, which will create more work for autovacuum.

Comment: Yes I know that, and I don't want to update all rows for the conflict seldom happens, so I asked this question. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: If the conflict rarely happens, then it shouldn't matter, because only few rows will get updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like this :

```
INSERT INTO table AS t (id, detail, areaid)
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET detail = CASE WHEN (t.detail IS NULL AND EXCLUDED.detail IS NOT NULL) 
                  THEN EXCLUDED.detail 
                        else 
                   detail end 
    ,
               areaid = CASE WHEN (t.areaid IS NULL AND EXCLUDED.areaid IS NOT NULL)
                              THEN EXCLUDED.areaid
                              else areaid 
                         end
```

Comment: Actually I know that, and I don't want to update all rows for the conflict seldom happens, so I asked this question. Anyway, thank you.